# No line number? TypeError {} (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

What do the curly braces mean? Is this an empty object? There is no line number, no script reference with this error and my code is very long with many scripts (So it would be highly silly for me to post a mountain of code).

```
TypeError {}
    (anonymous function)   //<----this is the stack also with no script line number
```

I am not asking for a fix, I would like to know what this is trying to tell me with these curly {} braces.

Any meaning?

These errors usually show a line number or name of the variable that had an unexpected type!?

Comment: A typeError is thrown when the value of something isn't of the exepected type, as in a method requiring an object being passed a string etc. Other than that, who knows ?

Comment: these errors usually show a line number or name of the variable that had an unexpected type!?

Comment: The only thing you would be able to do now is to start commenting out blocks of code to try and see where the error is occurring.

Comment: There may be a stack trace. check that

Comment: @scrblnrd3 - that is a great idea. Even if the stack trace doesn't point to the correct file you could find out that the error is happening (for example) from within the logic of some library. The location of the error within the library might hint at where (or what type) of code is causing the error.

Comment: I will try commenting out lines. thank you! but this does not answer my questions; why are there no line numbers? (btw (anonymous function) IS the stack. also with no line number)

Comment: @BenMuircroft Try leaving the console open, then refresh the page. This usually solves my problems where the console shows no stack trace arrow.

Comment: I know this trick lol, it shows nothing new in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem...

https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/issues/145

FIXED !Important Please read and update your code

My console log shows me this TypeError with no line number for the error

```
[WebSocket] response header:
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: EKe7xY9gtGUsL6JCb3hs1x2qLU8=

TypeError {}
    (anonymous function)
```

happens every time the same after/during upgrade response... server side the last thing that happens is

```
ws.on('connection',function(){
    console.log('connected');//-----------------<< I see this happens! then error on the client side
});
```

Where might this error come from? I think one of the .as files.... I am not familiar with how to compile and build an swf with all these files, I have Flash Professional CS5.5, I would like to try adding some more console log messages to the code so I can see exactly what is the last thing that happens before the error.
1 participant

benzmuircroft commented 4 hours ago 
I've completely commented out virtually every line of the einaros ws/lib/WebSockets.js file on my server so I think it cant be that my server is sending to the browser any data for the upgrade because I still see in my browser console log the same upgrade request and response then the typeError.

I think that the browser is sending this stuff and then throwing a fit of anger because it hasn't got an immediate response the same second...

is this correct?

benzmuircroft commented 3 hours ago

```
__onFlashEvent
```

when it tries the open event something goes wrong!

line 350 of web_socket.js is where The typeError comes from...

```
logger.error(e);
```

Please change this to:

```
logger.error(e+' web_socket.js:350');
```

What is wrong this with flash event?

```
{protocol: null
 readyState: 1
 type: "open"
 webSocketId: 0
 __proto__: Object}
```

is the protocol suppose to be null? where is this coming from if I've commented out most of my server ws code????
Closed

benzmuircroft commented 3 hours ago 
this line causes error:

```
WebSocket.__instances[events[i].WebSocketId].__handleEvent(events[i]);
```

benzmuircroft commented 3 hours ago

It throws an error because events[i].WebSocketId is not suppose to have a capital W

it should be:

```
WebSocket.__instances[events[i].webSocketId].__handleEvent(events[i]);
```

@ line 347 of [web-socket.js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/blob/master/web_socket.js)

Answer (score 0):

On the console, there should be a corresponding line number to that error.

Haven't tried in other browsers, but in Chrome, there's also an arrow on the left which expands to a stack trace, each step with line numbers of the involved functions. You can go to these lines and plant breakpoints to see what variables you have there.

Additionally, when you pause at the breakpoint, the console will run in that scope. You can test something like `typeof [variable_name]` or `[object] instanceof [constructor]` while paused to check on these values.

Comment: there is no line number dude. and the stack expands to show (anonymous function) also with no line number or script reference. when I press pause I see reference to an Object.observe.poly.js that has not yet even been used in the code (used for the first time about ten seconds later). but I am pausing after the error happens as the error happens very fast.

Comment: @BenMuircroft You can set an early breakpoint, and then step into the code (F11) until the error happens. That way, you can find the line where the error takes place.

Comment: http://i1201.photobucket.com/albums/bb358/Ben_Muircroft/break_zps6467a6cb.jpg I'm not quite sure what you mean